# Open files with spaces using intent Android

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri, android-package-managers

I am making an application which opens a file using another application. The problem is if the file name contains spaces there is an error-and exception is not showed -. I've tried `String.replace(" ", "\\ ");` but does not work.

My code seems like

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).
            getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyFolder", file);
    if (f.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File(f.getAbsolutePath().replace(" ", "\\ ")));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, getMimeType(file));

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName component = intent.resolveActivity(pm);

        if (component == null) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "There is not any application to open this file.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("LaunchApp", "There is not any application to open this file.");
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

File Path is like /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFolder/Photos/My Photo.jpg;

Result: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFolder/Photos/My%5C%20Photo.jpg

Otherwise: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFolder/Photos/My/ Photo.jpg and does not work neither.

What i want: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFolder/Photos/My Photo.jpg
 If I "hardcoded" the path, is not success.

Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by MimeType method.

```
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url.replace(" ", ""));
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
```

I took out all spaces from url(File Path), and now MimeType does not return null and then, startActivity works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace  `"%20"` to `"_"` because if you replace it to `"\\ "` you'll be creating a sub path which might not exist.

`f.getAbsolutePath().replace("%20", "_")`

Comment: If I replace for "_", file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String.replaceAll(" ", "%20")
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I've edited my question. The problem is not file path. Is URI given with that Path.

Comment: Yes it is URI but you have to encode file path to replace white space and special characters. you can try.                                                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File(URLEncoder.encode(f.getAbsolutePath(),"UTF-8")));

Comment: That's not i'm loking for. The real problem resides in I need path file literally and not encoding with URI. And URI gives me a path with encoded path.